# How to convert data (percentages) into z-scores?

Tags: data-transformation, z-score

I have data for total population and percentage of smoking for 10 cities. The data look like below:
[image]

How do I convert the percentage_smoke into z-score? Do I need to take into consideration of the population size for each city? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want the data to be a z-score?

Comment: It was an advice from a colleague so that we can have normal data. Nonetheless, the initial thought was to just look up the % and the corresponding z-score using the z table. But I am not sure if size of the city (population) should be considered when doing the z-scores.

Comment: The data are not normal by virtue of transforming them to z-scores.  Let me ask you this; what do you want to do with the data?  What analysis do you intend to perform?

Comment: I intended to compare the average % of smoking between two places. So the % of smoking are available for the two places in terms of different cities. I was told you cannot just do t-test for % data directly...

Comment: First, I don't think a t-test is a particularly good approach given we're working with proportion data.  Do you want to test between two cities in particular, or between all cities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to just perform a test of proportions between two cities (e.g. is does city 1 have the same proportion of smokers as city 2) then a t-test really isn't needed.  We can use `prop.test` in R to do this, but we need the number of smokers, not just the proportion.  We can fudge this a bit as follows:

```
#Your data
city = 1:10
population = c(13490, 8765, 45900, 3200, 32100, 9870, 90903, 6570, 23000, 8702)
p = c(9, 12, 20, 1, 22, 5, 13,3,10,32)/100
smokers = as.integer(round(p*population))
```

The difference between `smokers/population` and `p` is no larger than 1e-4, so I think this is suitable.  Next, All we have to do is choose which cities we want to do the `prop.test` with.  Let's test for differences between cities 1 and 2

```
prop.test(smokers[c(1,2)], population[c(1,2)] )

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  smokers[c(1, 2)] out of population[c(1, 2)]
X-squared = 52.063, df = 1, p-value = 5.374e-13
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.03846758 -0.02159289
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.08999259 0.12002282
```

If we want to test all cities against one another, we can use `pairwise.prop.test` which accepts as an argument a method for p-value correction

```
pairwise.prop.test(smokers, population, p.adjust.method = 'bonferroni')

Pairwise comparisons using Pairwise comparison of proportions 

data:  smokers out of population 

   1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      
2  2.4e-11 -       -       -       -       -       -       -       -      
3  < 2e-16 < 2e-16 -       -       -       -       -       -       -      
4  < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 -       -       -       -       -       -      
5  < 2e-16 < 2e-16 6.2e-10 < 2e-16 -       -       -       -       -      
6  < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 -       -       -       -      
7  < 2e-16 0.370   < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 -       -       -      
8  < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 6.3e-08 < 2e-16 2.0e-08 < 2e-16 -       -      
9  0.084   1.0e-05 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 -      
10 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16 < 2e-16

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

So that method tells us which cities have a statistically significant difference in proportion of smokers, but what about the entire population?  Can we estimate the proportion of smokers from the population in which the sample was obtained?  For instance, if these cities all came from the same state, then what is the proportion of smokers in that state?

To do that, I think we can turn to Bayesian models.  Warning, I'm posting this for interested readers, not as a serious solution.

This is a pretty simple hierarchical binomial model

$$\mbox{smokers}_i \sim \operatorname{Binom}(\theta_i, \mbox{population}_i)$$

$$ \theta_i \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) $$

And then we put a prior on the parameters of the beta distribution.

Here is some Stan code to fit the model

```
stan_code = '
data{
  int n;
  int smokers[n];
  int population[n];
}
parameters{
  real<lower=0, upper=1> mu;
  real<lower=0> eta;
  real<lower=0, upper=1> theta[n];
}
transformed parameters{
  real alpha;
  real beta;

  alpha = eta*(mu);
  beta = eta*(1-mu);
}
model{
  eta~cauchy(0,1);
  theta ~ beta(alpha,beta);
  smokers~binomial(population,theta);
}
generated quantities{
 int smokers_ppc[n];
 for (i in 1:n){
  smokers_ppc[i] = binomial_rng(population[i], theta[i]);
 }
}
'
```

And once we fit the model, our posterior for the population mean is

[image]

so if we *were* interested in the population mean, we would estimate that it is just shy of 15% (but is anywhere from maybe 0.08 to 0.225).  I'm being a bit slop[y here since I'm not showing any posterior predictive checks, but again this is for posterity and not a serious solution to your problem.